# how to keep the photo for the registration page

Tags: yii

i want to keep the photo column for the registration page so that user can select the image and display in that column for this i am using ImageSelect extension in yii framework but it is not working suggest me how to keep the image while registering the user

Here is my code for ImageSelect

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'profileImage'); ?>
    <?php
$this->widget('ext.imageSelect.ImageSelect',  array(
    'path'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/Penguins.jpg',
    'alt'=>'alt text',
    'uploadUrl'=> 'profileinfo/upload',
    'htmlOptions'=>array()
));
?>
```

my controller code is

```
public function actionUpload()
{

    $file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
    // Do your business ... save on file system for example,
    // and/or do some db operations for example

    $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/'.$file->getName());


    // return the new file path
    echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/'.$file->getName();
}
```

Comment: Post some code showing what you have tried

Comment: We need to know where it's going wrong! is `$file` containing the image (try a `var_dump` on it), is the image been saved in your `images` folder?

Comment: no image is not saving and by var_dump function also we cann't able to find it is just showing that is processing image at background.